# Sequence of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations

> Suppose that you have parameters $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$  and a matrix $A_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ where $A_{0}$ is a rotational matrix given like below
>
> $$ A_{0} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> Now suppose that
>
> $$  A_{i} = \begin{align}\begin{cases} \alpha  A_{i-1} &  i \textrm{ is even }     \\ (1+\beta) A_{i-1}   & i \textrm{ is odd }   \end{cases} \end{align}$$
>
> What can you say about the behavior of $A_{i}$ given the parameters $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You put a close tag on this within like 30 seconds? I just came up with this problem..

Comment: Perhaps you mean "close vote".  The $i$-th term is just a rescaling of the previous term.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A_i &= \begin{cases}
\alpha A_{i-1} & i \text{ is even}\\
(1+\beta) A_{i-1} & i \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\alpha(1+\beta) A_{i-2} & i \text{ is even}\\
(1+\beta)\alpha A_{i-2} & i \text{ is odd}
\end{cases} = (1+\beta)\alpha A_{i-2}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\alpha(1+\beta)\alpha A_{i-3} & i \text{ is even}\\
(1+\beta)\alpha(1+\beta) A_{i-3} & i \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}\\
\vdots\\
&=\begin{cases}
[\alpha(1+\beta)]^{i/2} A_{0} & i \text{ is even}\\
(1+\beta)[\alpha(1+\beta)]^{(i-1)/2} & i \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$A_{2i}=\alpha^i(1+\beta)^iA_0$ and $A_{2i+1}=\alpha^i(1+\beta)^{i+1}A_0$.